# Why is my button not expanding, even though I'm referencing jQuery before bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Afternoon, guys and gals!
I'm trying to teach myself some front-end stuff and I've hit a wall in this tutorial.
I'm trying to get this collapsible hamburger menu to work in my navbar. It shows up, but won't expand. This seems to be a pretty common problem, but the only answers I've found seem to suggest I reference jQuery before bootstrap, but I'm pretty sure I do. Here's the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <Title>Hey there, pal! @ViewBag.Title</Title>
    
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
        <header class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand">Welcome!</h1>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#theMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="theMenu" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="App" asp-action="Contact">Contact    </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="App" asp-action="About">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <h2>V@ViewBag.Title</h2>
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    <footer class="container">
        <div class="text-center">Copyright 2022 My Company LLC</div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/index.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone sees where I'm going wrong, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using please?

Comment: @War10ck v 5.3.1

Comment: So per the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) for this version, it looks like your data attributes are incorrect. They should be `data-bs-*`. So for example: `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#theMenu"`. Give that a go and see if that fixes it.

Comment: **Side Note:** You have an extra `V` character in front of your `@ViewBag.Title` property in your `<h2>` element below your `<header>`. Pretty sure that's a typo.

Comment: **Pro Tip:** If you'd rather not have to come back each year and update your copyright statement, you can make it dynamic by doing the following: `<div class="text-center">Copyright &copy; @(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())</div>`. This will update the year based on the current year.

Comment: @war10ck that seemed to work!! Thanks!!

Comment: Awesome, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/), it looks like the data attributes are incorrect. They should be defined as `data-bs-*` attributes. The following should work for you:

**Change:**

`data-toggle="collapse"` -> `data-bs-toggle="collapse"`

`data-target="#theMenu"` -> `data-bs-target="#theMenu"`